# Does NWChem support RI approximations in the MP2 part of double hybrids?

Tags: nwchem

I abandoned the use of M11-L and instead turned to B2PLYP for my molecule in my previous question, as M11-L seemed in fact to be very poor for my application. Since B2PLYP contains MP2, I looked up the NWChem manual to see if it supports RI-MP2 approximations. The manual did say that it supported RI-MP2, with explicit syntax rules on the fitting basis, but said nothing on RI-DH, let alone where to put the fitting bases in the code.

My question is now clear- does NWChem support RI approximations for the MP2 part of double hybrids, and, if it does, where does one put the fitting basis line in? Q-Chem seems to have the answers to both but I cannot use commercial packages outside of the WebMO demo server.

Comment: +1 but is there any reason why you're asking specifically about NWChem? It seems that what you wanted to do didn't work in Q-Chem and you're looking for a non-commercial alternative, but NWChem is not the only non-commercial electronic structure software.

Comment: I prefer to visualise it on WebMO.

Comment: The WebMO website says that it supports: "Gamess, Gaussian, MolPro, Mopac, NWChem, Orca, PQS, PSI, Q-Chem, TeraChem, Tinker, Quantum Expresso, and VASP". Included in that list is Orca, which is free, and can do RI-MP2 (as listed in the URL at the end of my second paragraph [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/9791/5)).

Comment: Didn't know ORCA was free

Comment: I'm not doing this work as an affiliate (currenrly majoring in something else)

Comment: I don't see anything telling me that you have to be majoring in any specific subject to use ORCA. There's also other software listed in my previous comment that is free, so it's not clear why this calculation needs to be done with NWChem. I say this because it's unlikely that this question will get an answer if only answers pertaining to NWChem are requested. If the question is broadened to allow answers pertaining to **any free software compatible with WebMO**, then the question would be much more answerable.